# new user with no posts and one rep, but with one suggested edit review and the custodian badge

Tags: discussion

Today I noticed a (for me) unknown user 'robinloop' reviewing suggested edits:

[image]

What baffles me is that this is a new user, without reviews:

[image]

---

IIRC you need some more reputation than **1** before you are allowed to review, unless you approve an edit on your own post. But there are questions nor answers by that user.

I checked if 'robinloop' accepted a suggested edit on his/her own Question and if that question was then moved to some other SX site, but there are no (close) votes today that indicate that such a thing happened.

Another possibility would be that a post was edited and the changes accepted by 'robinloop', after which the post was flagged and removed. But I would the edit information in that case not get reset?

Do I miss something on how things work, or is there a loophole in the system of voting on suggested edits (including getting the Custodian badge)? Therefore not sure if a discussion item or a bug either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19986) was on [robinloop's own post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78393/repositories-problem-linux-mint-14-whole-reconfig) like you guessed, but the post was subsequently deleted, so it doesn't show up in his profile